# A meager subgroup of the real line, which cannot be covered by countably many closed subsets of measure zero?

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, topological-groups

*Is there a ZFC-example of a subgroup $H$ of the real line $\mathbb R$ such $H$ is meager, has zero Lebesgue measure, but cannot be covered by countably many closed subsets of measure zero in $\mathbb R$?*

This question can be equivalently refolmulated as a question about the ZFC-example of a subgroup $H\subset\mathbb R$ that belongs to the family $(\mathcal M\cap\mathcal N)\setminus\mathcal E$.

Here $\mathcal M,\mathcal N$ and $\mathcal E$ stand for the $\sigma$-ideals of meager sets, sets of measures zero, and sets that can be covered by countably many closed sets of measure zero in $\mathbb R$.

**Partial Answers**:

1. Under $cov(\mathcal N)=non(\mathcal M)$ the real line contains a subgroup $H\in\mathcal M\setminus\mathcal E$.
2. Under $cov(\mathcal N)=cov(\mathcal M)=cof(\mathcal M)$ (in particular, under Martin's Axiom) the real line contains a subgroup $H\in(\mathcal M\cap\mathcal N)\setminus\mathcal E$.
3. No quasi-analytic subgroup $H\subset\mathbb R$ belongs to the family $\mathcal M\setminus\mathcal E$. 
   A topological space is *quasi-analytic* if it is a continuous image of a hereditarily Baire metrizable separable space. A space $X$ is *hereditarily Baire* if each closed subspace of $X$ is Baire. Since each Polish space if hereditarily Baire, each analytic space is quasi-analytic. Because of that (3) implies:
4. **Theorem ([Laczkovich, 1998](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1998-126-06/S0002-9939-98-04241-5/)).** Each proper analytic subgroup of the real line belongs to the $\sigma$-ideal $\mathcal E$.
5. **Theorem ([Talagrand, 1980](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm67/sm6712.pdf), [Roslanowski & Shelah, 2016](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.02261.pdf)).** The Cantor cube $\mathbb Z_2^\omega$ contains a subgroup (actually, an ideal on $\omega$) which is not meager but has measure zero.
6. **Theorem ([Burke, 1991](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/unpub/burke.pdf); [Pawlikowski, 1995](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1995-123-10/S0002-9939-1995-1264828-9/), [Roslanowski & Shelah, 2016](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.02261.pdf)).**  It is consistent that every meager subgroup of $\mathbb R$ has zero measure.

So, we ask about the consistency of a stronger fact: *Is it consistent that each meager subgroup of the real line can be covered by countably many closed sets of measure zero?*

More information on the items (1)-(3) can be found in this [preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.09073).

In this preprint we construct an example (6.3) of a meager Borel subgroup $H$ in the Polish group $G=\mathbb Z^\omega$ such that $H$ is meager and Haar-null but $H$ cannot be covered by countably many closed Haar-null sets in $G$. This example shows that the 'non-locally compact' version of the above problem has a `Borel' affirmative ZFC-answer. This example also gives a negative answer to the problem ([Can each non-open analytic subgroup of a Polish abelian group be covered by countably many closed Haar null subsets?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215632/can-each-non-open-analytic-subgroup-of-a-polish-abelian-group-be-covered-by-coun)).